# How to find out why import fails on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I generate a .sql file, on my laptop, that contains around 11 million insert statements into several tables.

Locally I run a MySQL database, into which I import this file. It takes a while, but it succeeds without any problems. The local MySQL version is:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16, for osx10.7 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

I want to import this file into a Google Cloud SQL instance. To do so, I first gzip the .sql file and upload it to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage.

Then I create a D0 pay-per-use instance (the least powerful / cheapest). I click 'Import' and enter the name of the file on cloud storage.

The import starts, but after a while (around a day) the import fails, stating: `An unknown error occurred`.

I tried this using a MySQL 5.5 and an experimental 5.6 instance, both fail at different inserts. (I can see what the latest successful insert was).

My problem is, I cannot find out what MySQL thinks is the problem.

How can I ask the Google developer console to show me a log? I tried on the Google APIs page which has a 'Logs' tab, but it gives me `An error has occurred. Please retry later.`

Maybe Google Cloud SQL has some limits on the insert statements that my local MySQL does not have?

One of the fields is a MEDIUMTEXT, which I believe can be larger than 65.536 bytes.

Any advice is appreciated.

---------- UPDATE -----------

I mailed with the cloud-sql team and they confirmed the problem was that the import timed out.
So indeed, 24 hours is the maximum time an import may take on Cloud SQL.

Solutions are: use a more powerful instance for the import (and use asynchronous replication), or split up the .sql in multiple parts.

Another approach is to use several values per insert statement, just make sure the line does not exceed 4MB. This is what the value of max_allowed_packet is on cloud sql. It speeds up the insert greatly.

In fact, this makes it possible to have the D0 instance import the file in a few hours, so I don't need to bump it to a more powerful one.

Comment: Import will time out after a day. That's probably the reason. Could you send an email to cloud-sql@google.com with your instance name so that we can verify that's the cause? Note that a D0 instance is underpowered. You might want to bump up the tier and change the replication to asynchronous for the import to go faster.

Comment: I think it is a good idea adding your update as an answer to the question